# two conditions in foreach

Tags: php, mysql

```
    foreach(($no_items as $key=>$txt ) && ($b_cost as $key=>$txt1 ))
    {
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO bulk_s (`no_items`,`b_cost`) VALUES ('$txt[$key]','$txt1[$key]')       ";
    }
```

I have two dynamically created arrays in my php page whose values I need to store in the DB in the same row

my js code

```
    function changeIt()
    {
    my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML +"<br> items <input type='text'  name='txt[]'+ i>"

    my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML +" cost <input type='text'  name='txt1[]'+ j>"
    i++;
    j++;
    }
```

Comment: sorry one's txt n other's txt1

Comment: you had different elements in the same array which you want to insert into same table......am i right

Comment: diff elements in two arrays txt and txt1  to be inserted in the same table

Comment: show your array or arrays and mention which elements you want to insert in those arrays........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `foreach` syntax isn’t valid PHP. If you want to iterate over two arrays with identical keys at the same time, you have to iterate over the keys instead:

```
foreach (array_keys($no_items) as $key) {
    $txt = $no_items[$key];
    $txt1 = $b_cost[$key];
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO bulk_s …";
}
```

However, note that [you should **never** construct SQL statements like this](http://xkcd.com/327/), it makes them liable to [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). This is an inacceptable coding practice. In the best case it makes your program less elegant, in the worst case it opens you up to lawsuit, and [there is a very simple superior solution](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: its working now, there was some problem with the query but now its fine. Thanks to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
  $i = 0;
foreach($no_items as $key=>$items) {

   $data[$i] = array(
           'variable1' => $items['no_items'],
           'variable2' => $items['b_cost'],
   );
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO bulk_s (`no_items`,`b_cost`) VALUES ('$data['variable1']','$data['variable2']')       ";
   $i++;

 }
```

Comment: key1 is the array element field name which he wants to access like this $items['order_id'];